# NoneType object BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a script which goal is to get comments number within this url : https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390?page=9999
So my script normally would get "190330 commentaires" but after some lines of script he finds NoneType object ? I scrape the exact balisetype with his class or id name.

Here is my script :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import re

###########################SEARCH##################
while(True):
    sent = 0
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
    cookies={"cookie_policy_agreement" :"3"}
    url = 'https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390#comments'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser') #sinon html5lib

    #Whole comments
    comments = soup.find("div", id="comments")
    comments = comments.find("section", class_="bg--main overflow--hidden bRad--fromW4-a")
    comments = comments.find("div", class_="space--h-3 space--v-3") #this is none object ?
    comments = comments.find("h2", class_="flex--inline boxAlign-ai--all-c")
    comments = comments.find("span", class_="size--all-m size--fromW3-l text--b overflow--wrap-off").text
    print(comments)
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, The problem is that I wrote a script to scrape the number of comments below (just above the last comment) except that after 2 "find" the objects are "NoneType" so I can't continue...
I comment the line in the part of "#whole comments#" with "#this is none object ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a tag's [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method returns `None`, it means that that tag has no child element that satisfies the provided criteria. In this case, the `<section>` element you found **has no** `<div>` inside it with the classes `space--h-3 space--v-3`. Looking at the page source at the link you provided, that is indeed the case. **There is no such `<div>`**.

Either way, it seems you are doing a lot of unnecessary `find` operations.

When an element on a page has an `id` attribute that usually means there will not be another element with the same `id`. Since you are looking for the number of "commentaires", I would try to start with the closest parent element that has an `id` attribute.

In this case, that seems to be a `<div id="thread-comments" ...>` closest to it. The line you are interested in also seems to be inside the only `<h2>` tag  below that aforementioned `<div>`, or at least definitely the first one. Thus I would suggest the following optimization:

```py
import re
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

comments_div = soup.find("div", id="thread-comments")
num_comments_line = comments_div.h2.get_text(strip=True)
# This is optional, if you actually want just the number itself:
match = re.search(r'^(\d+)\s+\w+', num_comments_line)
num_comments = int(match.group(1))

print(num_comments)  # output: 189010
```

Note that these two are equivalent: (see [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names))

```py
comments_div.h2
comments_div.find("h2")
```

The last bit is just a regular expression to grab the number from the string that looks like `189010  commentaires`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It print me "189010 commentaires" ? There is actually more than it ? Actually there is : "190331 commentaires"

Comment: @Feedain Sorry, I don't understand your question. The print statement in my code should print just the number `189010`...

Comment: I don't understand why it should print ```189010```while when you go to the website it shows more than ```189010```

Comment: @Feedain Ah, I was visiting the page while blocking JavaScript. Apparently they have a script that fetches the latest number... Well, that may or may not be a problem for you. Since regular `requests` don't do any JavaScript, but "see" the page as it is loaded in pure HTML, the number you will get that way will probably not be the latest one. If you need JavaScript support in your webscraping, you may want to look into [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), but this will get **much** less efficient.